# EF 6 Code First Error: EntityType has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have defined a class that holds the createby,createdate,modifyby and modifydate properties which is inherited by other classes { so that i don't have to create the field in all the entities that have those field}. My code is

```
public class SMSModelBaseClass
{

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Column(TypeName ="varchar")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string CreateById { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string ModifyById { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreateById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreateBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifyById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ModifyBy { get; set; }

}
```

Am getting the subject error. I know i could introduce a primary key for the same but it will get inherited by the other classes, something that i dont want.

Is it possible either using fluent api or data annotations to bypass this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EntityFramework, each entity needs a key property.

Typically this is an `Id` column.
It could be a composite key, but given your model, I would suggest an `Id` property on `SMSModelBaseClass`

As a side note, I believe `SMSModelBaseClass` should also be `abstract` if you are using it as a base class, and not instantiating it directly

Comment: Thanks for the side note....will implement that. If i put the Id column in the SMSModelBaseClass, when inherited by another class it will carry along its id column. I dont want the Id column in the other classes

Comment: You don't have a lot of choice I'm afraid - Each entity needs a Key column. It's either Id, or something else...